# IIS web.config redirect pages from one domain to another using specifi paths

Tags: regex, redirect, iis, path, url-rewrite-module

I'm trying to figure out if the following is possible on an IIS 7.5 server using web.config rewrite rules. We are moving pages from one domain to another. Here is the configuration.

Old domain page/path example:

https://www.olddomain.com/oldpath/news/2023/10/16/article-name/

New domain page/path example:

https://www.newdomain.com/newpath/news/2023/10/16/article-name/

The differences between the domains/paths are the domain itself and the first level path name. Everything else following the first level path name stays the name.

So basically the rewrite rule would look for a specific path structure /oldpath/news/dateyear/datemonth/dateday/article-name/ and forward via 301 redirect to newdomain.com/newpath/news/dateyear/datemonth/dateday/article-name/. Notice that the second level path name remain the same between domains "/news/".

The redirect would apply to the following examples:

- https://www.olddomain.com/oldpath/news/2023/10/16/article-name/ redirects to:
  https://www.newdomain.com/newpath/news/2023/10/16/article-name/
- https://www.olddomain.com/oldpath/news/2023/09/10/article-name/ redirects to:
  https://www.newdomain.com/newpath/news/2023/09/10/article-name/

The redirect would need to be path specific "/oldpath/news/"and not apply to pages that exist in non-defined paths. Eg: /about/, /contact/ etc.

Other conditions:

Date folders DO NOT need to be redirected but **its okay if they do**. Eg:

- https://www.olddomain.com/oldpath/news/2023/ DOES NOT NEED to redirect to:
  https://www.newdomain.com/newpath/news/2023/

Please and thank you.

Comment: You might either wait for someone to write the rules for you, or engage a modern AI to guide you through simple topics like regular expressions and IIS rewrite rules.

Comment: Apologies if my post wasn't formatted correctly or if there was missing information. I've only used SO half a dozen times. If you could kindly point out where it was wrong or incomplete, I'll be certain to update it and not make the same mistake down the road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, I wrote the following rewrite rule and tested it. It's work for me. I hope it can help you too. Please try the following rule:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to New Domain and Path" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^oldpath/news/(\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/.*)$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.olddomain\.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.newdomain.com/newpath/news/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Thank for for this, it's very close! Initially I wasn't sure why it was only working for some URLs and not others but it turns out that the month and day folders sometimes have only one digit EG: 2003/1/2 and don't use the two digit format required by the match pattern EG: 2003/01/02. Can the match pattern be modified to work with one AND/OR two digit month and day formats?

Comment: Found the solution. I needed to update the match pattern to use \d{1,2}. Thank you much for your help.